# Error updating user data: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

Tags: android, exception, parse-platform

```
public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here

    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("appchatid")
            .clientKey("appclientid")
            .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")   // '/' important after 'parse'
            .build());

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.

    //defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    Log.i("Parse", "onCreate: ");
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestApple");
    testObject.put("foo", "11234");

    testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                  // Saved successfully.
                  Log.d("TEST", "User data saved!");
              } else {
                  // The save failed.
                  Log.d("TEST", "Error updating user data: " + e);
              }
          }
      });
  }
}
```

this is the code. When I run it I am getting the error.

> Error updating user data:
>   com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

Comment: Looks like you're trying to hit a parse server on localhost, which is the android device where your app is running.  Presumably you want to hit your development machine, which unless someone has figured out how to do on a device, will require running the app in an emulator against https://10.0.2.2 or similar, not localhost.

Comment: i tried using 10.0.2.2 and then 10.0.3.2 which is the correct one, still it is giving same error i/o failure.

Comment: And are you running this on a device or emulator?  Because probably a device is not going to work.

Comment: tried it on emulator Genymotion.

Comment: Have you verified via cURL or some such that the parse server is working?

Comment: It works in advance rest client application plugin in google chrome. Used the url: http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/TestObject with header X-Parse-Application-Id: appchatid

Comment: @nasch [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/aaekr7nq8mlc312/wp_2.JPG?dl=0

Comment: OK I don't know what the issue is but it sounds like the problem is more generally connecting to your dev machine from the emulator rather than anything specific to parse server.  Have you tried searching for solutions to that problem?  Could be a firewall issue or something like that.

Comment: I uninstalled the firewall and turned off the windows firewall settings still it gives me i/o failure error.

Comment: How about my other question - have you searched for emulator -> localhost connection problems?

Comment: Thanks!! it worked now. Emulator was expired and had issue with it.

Comment: Purple, I have exactly the same problem. I'd tried from two different machines.  I'm working with Heroku installation of the parser server.. but I still get the same i/o error.
When doing the curl commands to POST/GET data it works ok.
Any idea guys?
Purple... I don't follow what your issue with Emulator was.... I'm running in a real device against my heroku version of parserserver

Comment: Answering my own question.... please make sure your device is connected to internet in order to perform any dumb test :)

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party here, but if you're testing on a real Android device and want to run the server locally, you can use the local IP address of the machine you're running the server on (in my case 192.168.0.6) instead of localhost and you should be golden :)

Answer (score 0):

The Main problem is that you are not connecting to the server.
[1]-make sure you have added your application id and  client id in manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
            android:value="https://parseapi.back4app.com" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="_App_Id_Here_" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="_client_Key_here_" />
```

[2]- add `repositories { maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } }` to your `build.gradle(Project:xyz)`

[3]- make sure u change the.server field to your parse server ex: "https://parseapi.back4app.com" to be

```
applicationId("appchatid")
            .clientKey("appclientid")
            .server("https://parseapi.back4app.com")  <-- this line is changed
            .build());
```